# Console Application on VB2008 - Integer.TryParse Method Error

Tags: vb.net, tryparse

I am using Integer.TryParse Method to validate whether user input is a numeric or non-numeric in my program.
1)if the user input is numeric, the program will then proceed and validate that the user input is range from 0 to 9. 
2)If the user is enter a non-numeric input, the program will display the message "invalid input" and ask user to start from beginning.

Following is my coding:
 Sub Main()

```
    Dim sevenNumbers As Integer()
    sevenNumbers = New Integer(6) {}
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim reEnter As Boolean = True

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter 7 integers: ")
    Console.WriteLine("<ATTENTION: FROM 0 TO 9 ONLY>")
    Console.WriteLine()

    While reEnter
        For index = 0 To 6

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the integer no." & "{0}" & " : ", index + 1) 'Prompt user to enter 7 integers.
            sevenNumbers(index) = Console.ReadLine() 'The 7 integers are stored in an array.

            If Integer.TryParse(sevenNumbers(index), number) Then
                While sevenNumbers(index) < 0 Or sevenNumbers(index) > 9
                    Console.WriteLine("<invalid input>")
                    Console.WriteLine()
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------")
                    Console.WriteLine("<Please re-enter the 7 integers>")
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------")
                    Console.WriteLine()
                    reEnter = True
                    Exit For
                End While

            Else
                Console.WriteLine("<invalid input>")
                Console.WriteLine()
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------")
                Console.WriteLine("<Please re-enter the 7 integers>")
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------")
                Console.WriteLine()
                reEnter = True
                Exit For

            End If

            reEnter = False

        Next
    End While
```

End Sub

However, when a user enter a non-numeric input, the program can't continue and shows an error that forced to close.

i tried this

Sub Main()
        Dim num As Integer

```
    Console.Write("enter num:")
    Dim input = Console.ReadLine

    If Integer.TryParse(input, num) Then
        Console.WriteLine("valid. num = " & num)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("invalid")
    End If
End Sub
```

it does works and i am wondering which part of my coding is wrong??

Thank for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two samples of code are different.  In your second attempt, you do this:

```
Dim input = Console.ReadLine 
If Integer.TryParse(input, num) Then
```

The above code reads into a variable called `input` that will be a `String` (because `Console.ReadLine` returns a `String`).  Then, you try to parse the string into a number.

However, in your original code, you do this (some lines omitted for clarity):

```
Dim sevenNumbers As Integer()  
sevenNumbers = New Integer(6) {}  
...
sevenNumbers(index) = Console.ReadLine()
```

In this case, you are reading into a variable that you have explicitly declared to be an `Integer`.  If the user types `"abc"` then the conversion will fail at this point - you won't even *get* to the `TryParse` because you can't complete the innput.

Instead of reading to an integer, you need to read into a `String` variable and then parse that value into an `Integer` (as you did in your second code).

You could have spotted this yourself by taking note of the line that the error actually occurs on when debugging: you should note that the program crashes on the `ReadLine`, *not* on the `TryParse`.

Comment: Yes, i have changed sevenNumbers to String instead of using integer and it does works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Um. This line:

```
sevenNumbers(index) = Console.ReadLine()
```

Is storing whatever text has been read into an array of `Integer`s. If it's compiling, then by the time you reach any later code, you're too late to control the conversion. It's already happened.

Maybe `sevenNumbers` should be `String()`?

(You really ought to turn on [`OPTION STRICT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`OPTION EXPLICIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) - it should find problems like this for you when it compiles the code)

Comment: Thank you for the tips and now i am able to run my program!